# React Native: ScrollView of Text Components not scrolling on Android But it is working on iOS

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using the ScrollView component in ScrollView (Main Screen) as shown in the GIF file. The problem is that this scrollView is working on iOS but not on Android Side. On an Android phone, it's stuck and not scrolling.

**ScrollView Component**

```js
<ScrollView style={{maxHeight:100,width: widthPercentageToDP('70%')}}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start',  marginBottom: 10 }}>

        {items?.map((item) => {
          return <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#e2cbff', paddingVertical: 6, paddingHorizontal: 10, marginTop: 10, marginRight: 10, borderRadius: 20, borderWidth:0.5, borderColor:'#461584'}}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 11, color: '#461584' }} >{item[itemKey]}</Text>
          </View>
        })}
      </View>
</ScrollView>
```

**Main Screen View in which I am using the component.**

```js
<View>
            <Text style={styles.personalInfoTitle}>Skills/Experties</Text>
            <ChipList items={profile?.expertises} itemKey='name'/>
</View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option,

```
<ScrollView>
  <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
  </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```